# "Puppet device" not working with catalyst 2950

Tags: cisco, puppet

I have setup the puppet and made suitable tweaking for puppet device management to work. I have device config set for my switch catalyst 2950. Certificate request and signing works good and when it comes to actually configuring my switch with puppet device command it fails with an error.

```
# puppet device -v 
Info: starting applying configuration to switch1 at telnet://root:password@192.168.33.93/
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for switch1
Info: Applying configuration version '1370021478'
Error: Could not prefetch interface provider 'cisco': Unknown switchport mode: dynamic  desirable for FastEthernet0/1
Notice: /Stage[main]//Node[switch1]/Interface[Fa0/1]/description: defined 'description' as 'Hello Switch'
Error: /Stage[main]//Node[switch1]/Interface[Fa0/1]: Could not evaluate: undefined method `command' for #<Puppet::Type::Interface:0x7fde25cc23a0>
Notice: Finished catalog run in 7.96 seconds
```

can I get some help??

Thanks,
vatsa

Comment: Seems like it has a problem with `switchport mode dynamic desirable` in the current config.  Dynamic's not good anyway, maybe switch it and its neighbor on that link to trunk mode if they need to be?

Answer (score 0):

There's a pull request with a fix available at https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/pull/4301. Apply the patch and it will work.